# cannot login frontend in opencart 1.5.6

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

If customer register with their new account then they cannot login their account and they just see Login page again and again without sending any error on console. They cannot even see "MyAccount" page after first time they register with their account. When customer enter login information on login page and hit the login button, page just refreshing without sending any error message also if you have any item in the cart, the item quantity increase with refresh page which happen when you click on login button.

If I use old customer user email and password for login customer account then its loges in and you redirect "MyAccount" page and it's working well.

If anybody have any idea about this, please share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You are better off using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) as it's a lot easier if you are doing cloud messaging. Also with **Google's Firebase** Cloud Messaging, You can Deliver and receive messages in a more reliable way across platforms and with authentication you have a lot less friction with acclaimed authentication.

Authenticating a user has never been more simple: Eg

[image]

**OR**

Saving an image to Cloud Storage: Eg

[image]